# Does this singleton pattern make sense?

Tags: objective-c

```
@implementation MySingletonClass
static MySingletonClass *sharedInstance = nil;


+ (MySingletonClass*)sharedInstance {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedInstance == nil) {
            sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

+ (id)alloc {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedInstance == nil) {
            sharedInstance = [super alloc];
            return sharedInstance; 
        }
    }
    return nil; 
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedInstance == nil) {
            sharedInstance = [super allocWithZone:zone];
            return sharedInstance; 
        }
    }
    return nil; 
}

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        // initialize stuff here
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Not sure if it's ok to overwrite both alloc and allocWithZone: like this...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this Singleton template. I've used it (once, ha ha! get the joke) and it has worked very well.

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to override alloc because the default implementation calls allocWithZone:

Other than that, you probably need to override some other methods.  See the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I've also used the [cocoawithlove](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html) template in many projects; Wikipedia's [answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Objective-C) is also good. As always, remember Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW31) is a good guide to how their frameworks and apps are constructed with singleton classes.

Just found this [implementation on github](https://github.com/cjhanson/Objective-C-Optimized-Singleton); tried it, and works nicely.